# Comparing algorithms

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose three algorithms are run on a machine that can execute one instruction every microsecond ($10^{-6}$ seconds).  They require, respectively, $n \log^2(n)$, $n \log^2(n)+5n$, and $n^2$ operations for a data set of size $n$.  Compare the time the algorithms require for data sets of size

a) $100$

b) $100{,}000$

c) $100{,}000{,}000$

Comment: You might find [this MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) handy in future.

Comment: @XxTIBZxX: Think about what $n$ represents here. Isn't it the number of operations the algorithm will perform (on average? best case? worst case?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it mean that an algorithm "requires $n \log^2(n)$ operations on a data set of size $n$" when $n = 100$ and each operation takes one microsecond to perform?
It means the algorithm requires $100 \log^2(100)$ microseconds to process that set of data.

But that's exactly what happens when the first algorithm has to process the first set of data.  So you need to evaluate $100 \log^2(100)$, which can also be written 
$100 \times (\log(100))^2$.  In other words, get your calculator out and find the decimal number that this expression is equal to.  That number is the running time of the first algorithm on the first set of data in microseconds.  To find the time in seconds, divide by $10^6$.

It will be necessary to know whether $\log(n)$ means common log (base $10$), natural log (base $e$), or log with some other base.  I would guess common log, since all the data sizes are powers of ten.

Similarly, write $100$ in place of each $n$ in the formulas for the other two algorithms and evaluate those expressions. Now you have the running times of the other two algorithms for the first set of data. Which one is largest (worst)? Which one is smallest (best)? Is there a large percentage difference between the two best running times? What about between the two worst?

Now do all of this again, except this time the number to plug into the formulas is $100,000$ instead of $100$.  And do it all a third time, this time for $100,000,000$.

Computer-science people like to talk about the asymptotic behavior of running time, in particular the fact that some parts of a formula for running time may cause one algorithm's running time to increase much faster than another algorithm's when you start using larger data sets.
We also say that some other parts of a formula for running time don't seem to matter very much for very large data sets even though they make a large percentage difference for small data sets.  The purpose of the exercise is apparently for you to experience these facts for yourself by trying some actual numbers in some formulas.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Makes perfect sense!